# Name of numbers in "to the power of" and factorial calculations

Tags: terminology, exponentiation, factorial

In $4*5=20$ , $4$ and $5$ are multiplicands and $20$ is the product. 
What are the names / labels of the numbers in the following expressions?

$2^3=8$

$4!=24$

Comment: *operands and result?*

Comment: is there no unique name for operands and results in context of these functions, as there are with multiplication?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b^a$, $b$ is usually called the *base*, $a$ is called the *exponent* and the result $b^a$ is called the $a$-th *power* of $b$. So in your case, the base is $2$, the exponent is $3$ and $8$ is the $3^{rd}$ power of $2$.

I'm not aware of any specific name for the operand of $n!$. The result is called the *factorial* of $n$, though.